# How do I find the charge on this capacitor in a complex circuit with multiple batteries?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance, batteries

[image]!

I have the answer to this question, it's 8*10^-6 C. But I have no idea how to get this answer.

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I wouldn’t answer a homework question, but this one seems deliberately tricky, so I’ll give a hint: Wires with nothing on them are shorted, and the voltage is the same everywhere along a shorted connection. Can you find any paths around the important capacitor which are shorted all the way to one or more voltage supplies? Can you figure out how much voltage drops across the capacitor?

Comment: I've got it now, thank you.